# Switch two fields in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my mobile structure:

```
A
B
C
```

And I need change to this other on desktop:

```
C
A B
```

I have tried to pull and push but I am unable to make it work.

My base code actually is like this:

```
<div class="col-md-? col-xs-12 col-md-push-?">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    A
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    B
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-? col-xs-12 col-md-pull-?">
  C
</div>
```

What's the correct method to do this?

Comment: why you are using `col-md-push-6` this will make margin-left to your text, you can change your first div `col-md-6 changed to col-md-12` that will make this result , remove pull push

Comment: To nest your content with the default grid, add a new .row and set of .col-sm-* columns within an existing .col-sm-* column.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I can't completly understand what you say

Comment: Have you considered using `flexbox` and utilizing the `order` property?

Comment: Hi Brett, I had not thought about it, but I'll try, since it might be the fastest solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with css, using flexbox and media query as follows:

```css
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
}
.wrapper > *{
  flex: 1 100%;
}
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
  .ab{
      order:2;
      flex: 1 auto;
    }
  .c{
      order:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="ab">A</div> 
   <div class="ab">B</div> 
   <div class="c">C</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: @neon_pc I hope, this is the result you are looking for, where C stays on top on desktops only.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and check. May this fit what you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 " style="background-color:black;">C</div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color:red;">A</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color:yellow;">B</div>
    </div>
  </div>






    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but, this doesn't solve the probblem. My interest is that block "C" don't stays always on top. I need block "C" stayis on top ONLY on desktop but no in mobile

Comment: @neon_pc. So we you to use some js for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can push/pull vertically using the Bootstrap grid system.

You would probably need some jQuery.

Here's a quick test: http://jsfiddle.net/uquf19rn/5/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row flexbox">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 a">A</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 b">B</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 c">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery test

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
      var win = $(this); //this = window
      if (win.width() >= 992) {
          $( ".flexbox div.c" ).append().insertBefore( ".flexbox div.a" );
      }
      if (win.width() < 992) {
          $( ".flexbox div.c" ).append().insertAfter( ".flexbox div.b" );
      }
}).resize();
```

(However - you can do a lot with eg. side-columns and the Bootstrap grid system. Example: http://www.bootply.com/1EcufJM6O4 )

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use the smallest Javascript code possible.

Comment: The jQuery in the answer is just a quick test to show that it can be done using jQuery. If you want a smaller jQuery code or you want to do it in plain javascript (without jQuery), you will have to do some searching or maybe post a new question, since I am not a strong javascript coder. The smallest possible javascript would be no javascript – like the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the order of columns in large screens.

So change the order of your columns.

```
 <!--Main Content-->
<div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-push-3">
</div>

<!--Sidebar-->
<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-9">
</div>
```

This displays the main content first.In mobile main content is displayed first.

By using col-lg-push and col-lg-pull we can reorder the columns in large screens and display sidebar on the left and main content on the right.

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8bxYr/38/).

I have find another solution also using **flex**. Use flex's order property for change order.

Comment: This is the theory, but when you try to do this with col-lg-push-12 or col-lg-pull-12 it breaks because I need to switch both blocks

Comment: try to in your code and show me. this is work for me.. May be I'll help you.

Comment: The example you show it's for a two blocks of the same field. I try to swtich two completly blocks. First to bottom and second to top.

Comment: As I said, your code is correct, but not to solve the question I propose.